# The elements of real analysis question

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let I2 denote the square I X I in R2. Show that any continuous function on I2  to R can be uniformly approximated by functions having the form f1(x)g1(y) + ... +fn(x)gn(y), where fi,gi; are continuous functions on I to R.

We define h(x)=f1(x)g1(y)+...+fn(x)gn(y)

since f and g are continuous then fg is continuous so h(x) is continuous

using the definition of continuity we have that for all epsilon>0 exists a delta>0 such that |x-a|

we don't know how to conclude that in R2 is possible

Comment: What the hell is $I^2$?

Comment: $I \times I = [0, 1] \times [0, 1]$.

Answer (score 1):

I presume $I$ is the unit interval. By the Stone-Weierstrass theorem,
continuous functions on $I^2$ are uniformly approximable by polynomials.